# subscribe to topic of laser in standalone version of gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I installed standalone version of Gazebo and i put a simulated pioneer3at in the environment with laser scanner, and i can get data of laser in shell with this command

```
gztopic echo /gazebo/default/pioneer3at/hokuyo/link/laser/scan
```

but i want to subscribe to this topic like [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/topics), anyone can help me???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2746/subscribe-to-topic-of-laser-in-standalone-version-of-gazebo/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Follow the tutorial in the link and instead of subscribing to ~/world_stats, replace the string with topic name you posted.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/default/ros/atlas_msgs/gazebo_ros_laser.cpp) is an example of subscribing to Gazebo laser topic.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-05-10**:
Thank you so much, I modify the listener for getting data of laser, i put [it](https://bitbucket.org/Vahid_Azizi/laser-listener-in-standalone-version-of-gazebo/src/a8c6d5e3677223ac9f738f091cb0fff1f14d3e8b/listener.cc?at=master) here.